# Detect page unload with JSF; influencing <body> tag from JSF

Tags: jsf, richfaces, facelets

I have a JSF web app which, after some user manipulation, opens a connection to an IBM MQ Q Manager, ie does something.
When the user navigates away from the page (using FF only) or closes the browser, I would like my app to detect this and close the connection gracefully.

All I can find thus far on the web are references to window.unload and use of the body tag.  I'm using RichFaces and Facelets so don't have a body tag.  How can I pass word of the above event to my bean in order to get it to do work when the user leaves?

*EDIT*
Respondents BalusC and Bozho are correct - there is of course a body tag but in my case I'm not specifying it explicitly, it's being generated;  my index.xhtml file contains this:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">

<f:view>...
```

after which I jump straight in using a4j and rich tags etc.  The questions therefore become (1): is the most efficient method to add attributes to the body tag to explicitly add a body tag with the attributes you want, or is there another way?  The question exists as I did not specify a body tag explicitly in my code, but one has been generated.  (2): What exactly generates the body tag in this context?

Comment: Open a page in webbrowser, rightclick and choose *View Source*. The `<body>` tag is there.

Comment: Yes. Sorry - see question update.

Comment: The updated question still stands though - what's the most efficient method of adding the body tag with the attributes I require?

Comment: Just write JS accordingly. JS has access to `body` element. See Bozho's answer. JSF is actually completely irrelevant here. It's all about its generated HTML output as the webbrowser has retrieved. JS sees nothing else than the HTML DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You do have a `<body>`, and you must have one
2. Use the solution that you find, and execute your `<a4j:jsFunction>` on `window.unload`, which in turn calls the server to finalize whatever has to be finalized
3. You'd better not rely on this - configure a reasonable connection timeout so that it can die gracefully when enough time passes.

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily add atribbutes to any tag using jQuery. In Richfaces you can use tag

```
<rich:jQuery>
```

So to add atribbute to body you would do this:

```
<rich:jQuery selector='("body")' timing="onload" query="attr('atribbuteName', 'atribbuteValue')" />
```

Comment: will this detect page unloads?